# How to get just value from lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, view

Hello everybody I need your help to show just value from a lambda expression.
this is what I got... (Y)

**code**

```
@foreach (var item in solicitudes)
{
     <td>
         @(solicitudes.Where(x => (x.TipoSolicitud == item.TipoSolicitud)).Select(x => new
         {
             item.Descripcion
         }).SingleOrDefault())
     </td>
}
```

**Result on my view**

```
{ Descripcion = descripcion 1 }
{ Descripcion = descripcion 2 }
```

**I want this, please help**

```
descripcion 1
descripcion 2
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Unclear what you asking. Your question title refers to using `Html.DisplayFor()` but nowhere in your code do you use it. And what is the purpose of your query. You could just use `@foreach (var item in solicitudes) { @item.Descripcion }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is printing an object, not a string. Don't do `x => new {x.Descripcion}` but just `x => x.Descripcion`

```
@foreach (var item in solicitudes)
{
     <td>
         @(solicitudes
            .Where(x => (x.TipoSolicitud == item.TipoSolicitud))
            .Select(x => x.Descripcion)
            .SingleOrDefault())
     </td>
}
```